# Is it possible to use an Eagle Eye accessory on SSF4 on PS3?

Tags: ps3, keyboard, super-street-fighter-iv

Is it possible to use the [Eagle Eye](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040UAYI4) accessory on a PS3 to play Super Street Fighter 4 with a keyboard, with the same configuration ?

I use on the PC the combination WASD + UIO (punch) + JKL (kick).

I own SF4 on PC, and definetely can't achieve the same proficiency playing this game with an arcade pad or with the SIXAXIS controller.

Comment: It looks promising that you can use it as you describe. You might get a better answer by asking the manufacturer themselves though. Then you can come back here and answer your own question.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan, sorry, but isn't the whole point of a Q&A site to ask questions and someone else answer ? Maybe the question wasn't phrased well enough, but my intent is not to know what the manufacturer tells, but if another user that has this device actually used it with this specific game.

Comment: No good so far. Just read some reviews, **no mention of SF4**. http://www.findps3.com/ps3-controller/eagle-eye-converts-keyboard-into-ps3-controller/ and http://loot-ninja.com/2010/09/15/review-ps3-eagle-eye-adapter/ Just a small mention on http://www.psu.com/Eagle-Eye-Converter-Review--a010529-p2.php0

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question here, but it's a good idea to give others a day or two to provide answers first. I can't see many people knowing the answer to your question though.

Comment: It's obviously targeted at the FPS market, so it's not surprising that SF4 isn't mentioned. But the Amazon page suggests you can fully customise the keys. To me this would include the D-pad, but it's too vague to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See my query to their sales department:

```
Hello, 
Yes the Eagle Edit 2.0 allows you to assign d-pad to any key configuration
you choose for your keyboard.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Best Regards,
Xxxxx
Penguin United Forum
Eagle Eye Support Page


From: xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx [mailto:xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx] 
Sent: Friday, March 11, 2011 11:42 PM
To: customerservice@penguinunited.com
Subject: Someone submitted the form from your 'Contact Us' page

Someone submitted the form from your 'Contact Us' page
A user has submitted the contact form on your store.
Here are their details:
Email Address:  xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx

Order Number:   

Does the PS3 Eagle Eye support remapping the controller's D-pad to keyboard
keys? I'm looking to control a fighting game using just the keyboard.

Penguin United Store 
http://www.penguinunitedstore.com/ 
________________________________________
Penguin United Store is powered by Big Commerce. Launch your own store for
free with Big Commerce.
```

The reasoning for my question about the D-pad was this:

- The Eagle Eye is designed for keyboard/mouse control of FPS games.
- Buttons such as X, Triangle, Square, R1, etc will be mappable to keyboard keys, as this is required for FPS games.
- Movement in FPS games will be mappable to the mouse, as this is a key FPS requirement.
- If movement can also be mapped to the keyboard, then a fighting game such as SSF4 can be played.
- SSF4 players generally use the D-pad for movement.

Therefore, since the D-pad can be mapped to the keyboard, the Eagle Eye can be used to play SSF4 with the keyboard. (Eagle Edit 2.0 is the packaged software for configuring the Eagle Eye.)